# How do I convert a sequence of words into an attribute?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, string, inflector

I need to turn:

```
"First Name".some_method = "first_name"
```

I guess I could just use a regular expression, but wanted to know if there was something better. I tried `constantize`, and `humanize`, and this is pretty much the opposite of what I need to accomplish:

```
"first_name".humanize = "First name"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
"First Name".gsub(/\s+/, '_').downcase
# => "first_name"
```

Comment: Why the downvote ? seems like someone downvoted all the answers.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but he's looking for a solution without regexes and you provide an answer with a regex. Maybe that was the reason for the downvote.

Answer (score 1):

```
"First Name".parameterize.underscore # => first_name
```

Answer (score -1):

```
require 'active_support/core_ext'

"First Name".gsub(/\s/, '').underscore # => "first_name"
```

I wasn't able to find the single method, though.

Answer (score -1):

```
  irb(main):017:0> "First Name".downcase.gsub(' ', '_')
  => "first_name"
```

Comment: why down vote? ..who give the down vote ?

Answer (score -1):

Use then `String#tr` as below:

```
"First Name".tr(" ", '_').downcase
# => "first_name"
```